# PHP download script, downloads automatically instead of prompting as it should

Tags: php

I have a script that starts a download in PHP. When users click on the link that starts the download it should prompt the user whether they want to save the file or not. It works fine in firefox, but in Safari and Chrome the download starts automatically without prompting the user.

Here is my code

```
$extension = fileexten($filename);
    if(($filename!= false)&&($fakename!=false&& @fopen($filename,'r')==true)){
    $mime = contenttype($extension);
    set_time_limit(0);
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0'); 
    header("Content-Type:".$mime);
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);        
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$fakename.'.'.$extension);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

      if (ob_get_length() > 0) {
        ob_end_clean();
        }
    flush();
    readfile($filename);
    }
    else{
    $error = "<h3>We could not find this file</h3>";} // If the filename or fake filename could not be retrieved.
```

}

Is there anyway I can make sure the browser prompts them to save or download the file rather than it start automatically in other browsers?

Comment: That's a browser-controlled behavior and you can't change that from PHP.

Comment: That's the standard behaviour for those browsers. I'd be annoyed if I had to deal with a prompt for a download.

Comment: What's the mime-type of what your'e sending out? If you use something invalid, or not-likely-to-be-configured in the user's browser, they'd get a prompt. But if they've told their browser to autosave (say) pdf files, then there's NOTHING you can do to override that, short of sending out a mime-type that lies and says "this is not the pdf you are looking for"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with a script but a browser setting.

In case of Google Chrome that's how you change it:

[image]